# Recursive function to reverse a number

Tags: javascript, recursion

I tried to use a recursive function to reverse a number it works but for one call only it's because of scoping i guess but i don't know how to fix it

```
let num;
let reversed='';
let result; 

function reverseNum(n){ 
 
  for(let i =0; i<n; i++){  
    num = n%10; // get the last digit e.g 352 %10 = 2
    reversed+= num
    result = parseInt(n / 10); // remove last digit e.g. parseInt(352/10) = 35
    reverseNum(result);
    if(result ===0){ 
        break;
    } 
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the `num`, `reversed`, and `result` variables to be created anew each time the function is called externally. Here's one simple tweak, by defining the recursive function inside the top `reverseNum` function:

```js
function reverseNum(n) {
  let num;
  let reversed = '';
  let result;
  const recurse = (n) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      num = n % 10; // get the last digit e.g 352 %10 = 2
      reversed += num
      result = parseInt(n / 10); // remove last digit e.g. parseInt(352/10) = 35
      recurse(result);
      if (result === 0) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return reversed;
  };
  return recurse(n);
}

console.log(reverseNum(1234));
console.log(reverseNum(1234));
```

But a more elegant method would be:

```js
function reverseNum(n, str = String(n)) {
  const thisDigit = str[str.length - 1];
  const recursiveResult = str.length === 1 ? '' : reverseNum(str.slice(0, str.length - 1));
  return Number(thisDigit + recursiveResult);
}

console.log(reverseNum(1234));
console.log(reverseNum(1234));
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work if num, reversed, and result were created inside the function body without defining the recursive function inside the top reverseNum function ?

Comment: Because *You need the num, reversed, and result variables to be created anew each time the function is called externally.*. In your original code, on subsequent calls, the old variables from the previous call are being used.

Comment: Note that your "more elegant method" will fail when the digits include zero: `reverseNum (8675309) => 935768`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reverse(number){
        let index = 0 ; 
        let reversed = '';
        let max = `${number}`.toString().length-1;
        while(index  <= max ){
             reversed += `${number}`.charAt(max-index)
             index ++;
        }
        return reversed;
}

console.log(reverse(546))
```

Answer (score 0):

CertainPerformance has explained why your code wasn't working.

Here is another implementation, one I find reasonably simple:

```js
const reverseNum = (n) =>
  n < 10
    ? String(n)
    : String (n % 10) + reverseNum (Math .floor (n / 10))


console .log (reverseNum (8675309))
```

Note that this returns a String rather than a Number.  If we wanted to, we could make this a private function and make a public function one which called this and converted the result back into a number.  But that would have the weird effect that reversing, say, 1000 would yield 1, since `0001` is simplified to `1`.  And that would mean that when you reverse again, you don't get anything like your original value.  So I choose to keep with a String.

Of course if we're going to do String reversal, perhaps we're better off just using a String reversal function in the first place:

```js
const reverseStr = (s) =>
  s.length == 0
    ? ''
    : reverseStr (s .slice (1)) + s [0]

const reverseNum = (n) => 
  reverseStr (String(n))
  
console .log (reverseNum (8675309))
```

Or if we weren't interested in doing this recursively, we could just write the more common string reversal function:

```js
const reverseStr = (s) =>
  s .split ('') .reverse () .join ('')

const reverseNum = (n) =>
  reverseStr (String (n))
  
console .log (reverseNum (8675309))
```